# Spring Data Redis Template ConvertAndSend Duplicate Messages

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I have a messaging application built over redis, however, I noticed the spring data redis template's convertAndSend may be duplicating messages as the message listener receives duplicate messages one in every three trials.

As you can imagine this may not be good for certain applications, in my secondary storage is complaining about duplicate keys.

I register the message listener in a @Configuration annotated class as:

```
@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer container(JobsListener receiver, RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    MessageListenerAdapter jobsMessageListener = new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(jobsMessageListener, new PatternTopic(RedisCacheService.JOBS_KEY));
    return container;
}
```

And in the JobsListener implementation, I use the onMessageReceived method.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
    System.out.println(new String(message.getBody()));
    Job job = cacheService.processNextJob();
    if (job != null) {
        logger.debug("Job id processed is " + job.getId() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        update(job);    
    } else {
        logger.debug("Job id processed is null");
    }
}
```

However, if I add synchronized to the onMessageReceived method it seems to fix this.

Is there a reason why synchronized helps? Smells like some concurrency issue under the hood.

Comment: Sounds like there are multiple `RedisMessageListenerContainer` instances. You can check what's going on using the `MONITOR` command and `CLIENT LIST`/`PUBSUB NUMPAT` commands.